# Windows Store App with Exchange Web Services (EWS) - Password change troubles

Tags: windows-store-apps, exchangewebservices

I'm working on a Windows Store App (Target: Windows 8 & 8.1; Dev Environment: VS 2012, Windows 8.1) that communicates with an Exchange Server (office365) using EWS. I've got most of it figured out but I am facing an issue and am not sure how to go about fixing it.

Here's how the problem is created:

1. Log in to exchange with user account XYZ through the App
2. Change the password for user XYZ through OWA
3. Fetch data from the exchange server through the App

The problem is that at 3, I am able to fetch data through the App even though the password has changed. I have verified that the password has, in fact, changed, by logging in through OWA (the old password does not work but the new one does).

I have tried

1. restarting the app
2. uninstalling the app before running it again
3. restarting the dev machine before running the app again
4. waiting 15 minutes (It's now been 16 hours since I changed the password) before trying again

but I'm still able to fetch data from Exchange without specifying the new password. My guess is, the session is saved somewhere on the local machine and it does not get invalidated even when the password has changed. But I haven't been able to figure out where.

What's weird is that I see the same behavior in Outlook. Outlook is able to sync with the Exchange server without requiring me to enter the new password.

I'm trying to figure out how to get the App to stop communicating with the server when the password is changed. The solution does not have to be programmatic.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried the same thing. With Apps + EWS but did not even get the "login" to work. How did you implement it? - Do you have any resources or tutorials to read?

Comment: @Martin Getting EWS to work, for me, involved a lot of trial and error. This link worked for me. I think, it should help you log in: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/416b66b6-052e-4337-8198-3a4a7575308a/problem-getting-http-to-work-with-exchange-web-services?forum=wcf

Comment: Facing the same scenario in my application. Was/Is there a solution available to this ?